# Popup mailform when clicking on a email-address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, joomla

I'm currently trying to add a functionality to my firm's new and upcoming website.

We are currently nine people in the firm, with each of our own email-address', and what I would like to add, is a popup-window functionality with an email-form inside of the popup-window. But the twist is, for when a person from the outside clicks on an email-address, the person writes directly to that person's (within the firm) email-address (Does it make any sense ?).

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LChEQ/), just to give an example

Here is a preview of the code too:

```
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="50px">CEO<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
            <td height="50px">Sales<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
            <td height="50px">Sales<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="50px">Sales<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
            <td height="50px">Sales<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
            <td height="50px">Driver<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
            <td width="100px" height="100px">Picture</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="50px">Driver<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
            <td height="50px">IT<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
            <td height="50px">IT<br />E-mail: <a href="mailto:test@test.org">Test-mail</a><br />Unique popup-emailform</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you started on the code for the popup then? If so, please share it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Joomla, as you tagged your question with Joomla. You can use the modal-functionality of Joomla.

Start by overriding the contacts - view in your own template. Copy the file 
/components/com_contact/views/category/tmpl/default_items.php 
to
/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_contact/category/default_items.php

Somewhere the top of the file add

```
<?php JHTML::_('behaviour.modal'); ?>
```

this makes a modal popup of all links with class=modal

Now make your email-links like this:

```
<a class="modal" href="<?php 
echo JRoute::_(Juri::root()."?option=com_contact&view=contact&tmpl=component&id={$contact_id}"; 
?>">Test-mail</a>
```

where $contact_id is the contact id of your employee. So you also need to add your contact-info in the contacts-component. The link should now open a modal dialog with a contact form for your employee.

More info here: [Using modal windows with Joomla](http://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Joomla-Tips/using-modal-windows-with-joomla.html)

regards Jonas